# Installing Theano on windows 8.1 with Anaconda: setting the system path configuration script

Tags: python-2.7, installation, windows-8.1, anaconda, theano

I’m trying to install Theano on windows 8.1 64 with Anaconda following step by step the guide provided here: http://theano.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install_windows.html.
I get stuck with the environment configuration script 'env.bat' needed to configure the system path.
The example refers to a WinPython distribution but as I’m installing in Anaconda and I don’t know how to configure that specific row.

This is the example for WinPython:

```
REM add winpython stuff
CALL %SCISOFT%\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\scripts\env.bat
```

Which directory should I set here after the CALL considering I’m using Anaconda? Struggling quite a lot, could anyone please help?

EDIT: please note that SCISOFT is the directory where WinPython is installed in the tutorial, the author says: "The script assumes that you installed WinPython distribution, update the winpython line otherwise." and that is what I'm not able to do because it is not specified what to point at.

I'm including the whole .bat, though I have no problem with the other settings:

```
REM configuration of paths
set VSFORPYTHON="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0"
set SCISOFT=%~dp0
REM add tdm gcc stuff
set PATH=%SCISOFT%\TDM-GCC-64\bin;%SCISOFT%\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64mingw32\bin;%PATH%
REM add winpython stuff
CALL %SCISOFT%\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\scripts\env.bat
REM configure path for msvc compilers
REM for a 32 bit installation change this line to
REM CALL %VSFORPYTHON%\vcvarsall.bat
CALL %VSFORPYTHON%\vcvarsall.bat amd64
REM return a shell
cmd.exe /k
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is in the WinPython env.bat, but you probably can just delete it. You likely just need to make sure that Anaconda is on the PATH.

Comment: I actually deleted it and I could proceed further (to get stuck again on a nastier issue) but you are right, in Anaconda that line can be ignored. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

next winpython should have theano working out of the box https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/lta_34FXIwg

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems and so I compiled a solid guide on how to install Theano on Windows 8.1 x64, using WinPython x64 and CUDA 7 with MS Visual Studio 2012 - CPU and GPU both set up.

http://machinelearning.berlin/?p=383

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Christian, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Hi, I wanted to advocate using WinPython instead as people are repeatedly having problems getting Anaconda to work with Theano. WinPython is free and can be installed in parallel to Anaconda - this would probably be much quicker than fixing the Anaconda problem. The whole process of setting up Theano with WinPython is too long to post here, so I don't understand why you have downvoted my answer. I understand the problem with links in answers, but this seems to be a situation where it's unavoidable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Christian, if the link expires no answer is left, your article does not look to long (*include the essential parts of the answer *). If a question can not be answered, without requiring a book to answer it, it should be closed as to broad, I don't think this is the case here.